# Ищу расширение для отображения имени атрибута как в WebStrorm для Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

Ищу расширение для отображения имени атрибута как в WebStrorm для Visual Studio Code.
(То что хочу указано на картинке.)

[image: Img]

Answer (score 2):

Нашел расширение для JS, JS React, TS, TS React, PHP.

[Parameter Hints - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DominicVonk.parameter-hints)

UPD:
В [обновлении 1.60 VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_inlay-hints-for-javascript-and-typescript) теперь есть такая возможность для JS, TS.